# Can Spark be run alongside Kafka on the same node to optimize by keeping the Spark Streaming ETL processes closer to real time data?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have gotten the advice, and, read in a few places, that running Spark on the data nodes greatly improves the performance of batch processing. I have also gotten the advice to keep the Kafka service isolated on dedicated nodes.

If most of the consumers of Kafka data are Spark Streaming ETL processes that land a transformed version of the data either back on Kafka or some other storage mechanism, does it then not make since to run those process on the same nodes i.e. run the Spark Service alongside the Kafka service on the Kafka dedicated cluster?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose the only way to really tell is for someone to run benchmarks.

Comment: Yea, I agree. We are still working on getting our physical hardware (benchmarking local performance doesn't make since) and once we do, or we get an extra cloud solution, I will try to do this and post the results. The only issue with a cloud environment is that benchmarks might differ depending on how storage is handled because of Kafka's filesystem based approach. I believe block storage is mostly used which will likely offer a higher latency.

Comment: Who is your cloud provider? [Amzaon EBS can do SSD](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ssd-backed-elastic-block-storage/)

Comment: [This might be relevant to you](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0waELw4QFt4J:https://grey-boundary.io/load-testing-apache-kafka-on-aws/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). (Cache link because the original site does not load for me.)

Comment: I did some research: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/what-is-the-story-with-aws-storage, older but thorough http://blog.scalyr.com/2012/10/a-systematic-look-at-ec2-io/. The issue isn't the disk but rather EBS not being directly attached to the instance, therefore there is higher latency with EBS. There are however EC2 instances with good ephemeral storage (I2 i think...), a couple dedicated servers of those might work well. We are however attempting to get our own personal team environment built in an internal cloud (rackspace). I will have to check on monday what the storage options are.

Comment: Thanks for the links. "Get your own" as in in-house servers? I suppose you should give Kafka its own disks/raid volume, separate from OS and everything else